# Sparql DBPedia not returning foaf:name query

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using the Virtuoso SPARQL endpoint for DBpedia. I am having no issue running some test queries, but my issue is when I run on a query based on the `foaf:name "literal"` of an entity. Here is my code below:

```
prefix db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix foaf: <http://xlms.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT ?capital WHERE{
        ?state dbo:capital ?capital .
        ?state foaf:name "State of Alaska"@en .
        }
```

My logic is that by `?state dbo:capital ?capital` refers to the capital of a state within DBpedia owl ontology. `?state foaf:name "State of Alaska"@en` should match the variable `?state` up with the literal entity `Alaska`. I am having no issue when my queries are controlled by variables that are not `foaf:name`. I have looked up examples and can't see what the issue is with my syntax. Even when I edit the last line to --

```
?state a foaf:name "State of Alaska"@en .
```

-- the code continues to fail. I have looked up other examples and can't find my specific issue. It appears as if this code SHOULD return the capital for Alaska based on the `foaf:name` Literal.

Comment: `?state a foaf:name "State of Alaska"@en .` -> that is clearly **not** a triple pattern!

Comment: and the main issue is, your FOAF namespace is just wrong, it must be `xmlns` instead of `xlms` -> `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. The key is to not add this prefix at the top

```
prefix foaf: <http://xlms.com/foaf/0.1/>
```

That should be replaced with the correct `foaf:` prefix declaration:

```
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
```

Or probably even skipped, since the `foaf:` prefix is [predefined](https://dbpedia.org/sparql?help=nsdecl).

So the query below actually works:

```sql
SELECT ?capital WHERE {
        ?state dbo:capital ?capital .
        ?state foaf:name "State of Alabama"@en .
}
```

Comment: Really, the key is to not have typographical errors in your SPARQL (which does require `prefix` declarations for all prefixes used in a given query, even though that endpoint has a predefined `foaf:` prefix).